# ruby: how to do a async callback in OO ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a ruby class called `class App` in app.rb
it has a instance variable called `@ui`
if `@ui.draw` is called, the gui is redrawn.

I want to monitor a .txt file, and if the size of the file changes I want to call the above mentioned .draw method.
How can I do this? Is it possible to do a hook / callback perhaps

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer to my own question. You can use the concurrent-ruby library.
It has a TimerTask object and a Observer facility.

Answer (score 0):

You could start a thread to monitor the last modified time. You should probably implement this in its own class.

```
Thread.new do
  last_changed_at = nil
  path = "/path/to/file.txt"

  loop do
    file_mod_time = File.mtime(path)

    @ui.draw if last_changed_at && file_mod_time != last_changed_at

    last_changed_at = file_mod_time

    sleep 1
  end
end
```

Comment: i doubt if a thread block has access to the scope that contains @ui